# Missing input parameters error on opt-out form

Tags: civimail, opt-out

Our site is producing fatal "Missing input parameters" errors from the mailing opt-out form.  This happens several times every day at random times. I have looked at a few other SE posts with similar errors, but those issues seem unrelated. The log output is lengthy so I dumped it [here](https://pastebin.com/6YLgtHiB).  If anyone could decipher it and let me know how to debug this, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems like it might be happening because one of the jid, qid, h params  are not present.

As a first step - I'd make sure that the opt out was working properly with a test contact (send them an email and opt out via the link and confirm it's working).

Then if that is working I'd check your server logs - it's possibly something hitting the url without the correct params (some sort of automated crawl etc).

If you wanted to you could try editing the file /home/user/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php  on line 31 and output further information about the request. Definitely back up that file first!

Comment: Thanks @Luke Stewart.  I tested the optout with a dummy account and it worked fine, so I am less concerned about this issue in general.  However I did look at the logs and isolated the IPs hitting the page without parameters. And as you suggested, there were some spiders plus a few sketchy IPs from Bucharest.  It's annoying that they are filling up the log, but otherwise I can ignore it.  Thanks!